# How to copy an instance in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

For example. I got a `UISearchBar` which I wanted to make a totally same copy.

I think it could be done by implementing the `copy(with:)` (`copyWithZone:`) of `NSObject` and then call the `copy()`.

But what I don't know is what to do inside the `copyWithZone` in Swift.

**I just need a copy of the `UISearchController`'s `UISearchBar`.**
Let's say we have a topic about how to copy an instance.
How to make that happen?

Comment: How would you do that with `swift3` ?

Comment: why you want to copy UISearchBar ? What is your requirement ?

Comment: Do you mean to make another instance of a class? Please clarify what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Create a factory method instead or a configure function that takes a UISearchBar instance as an argument

Comment: @Chris Plz check my update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UISearchBar **cannot** be copied as it doesn't adopt NSCopying.

You have to create a new instance of `UISearchBar` and apply the customizations, for this you can *also* create an struct that holds the settings, like so:

```
struct SearchBarConfig {
    var placeholder: String?
    var isTranslucent: Bool

    // Display Attributes
    var barStyle: UIBarStyle
    var barTintColor: UIColor?
    var searchBarStyle: UISearchBarStyle
    var tintColor: UIColor!

    init(isTranslucent: Bool, barStyle: UIBarStyle, searchBarStyle: UISearchBarStyle) {
        self.isTranslucent = isTranslucent
        self.barStyle = barStyle
        self.searchBarStyle = searchBarStyle
    }
}

let existingSearchBar = UISearchBar()
var existingStatusBarConfig = SearchBarConfig(
    isTranslucent: existingSearchBar.isTranslucent,
    barStyle: existingSearchBar.barStyle,
    searchBarStyle: existingSearchBar.searchBarStyle)
```

Now if you have above implemented, you can just create a new searchBar and apply the attributes.

Comment: So there is no convenient way?

Comment: UISearchbar does inherit from NSObject. It doesnt adopt NSCopying though.

Comment: @JsW "Why UIView cannot adopt NSCopying"?, refer to this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/1552137, I like how Frank explained in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1556426/1244597

Comment: `UIView` inherit from `UIResponder` which inherit from `NSObject`

Comment: @JsW Although UIView does inherit from NSObject (as almost all classes in Objective-C) do, that does not mean that it adopts the NSCopying protocol.

Comment: @Abizern yeah, I realized it now :p